# Parse json date string in android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I get a json string with number of milliseconds after 1970 from the server in my android app.

Looks like this: `\/Date(1358157378910+0100)\/`.

How can I parse this into a Java calendar object, or just get some date value from it? Should I start with regex and just get the millisecons? The server is .NET.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The time seems to also have the timezone there so I would do something like this:

```
String timeString = json.substring(json.indexOf("(") + 1, json.indexOf(")"));
String[] timeSegments = timeString.split("\\+");
// May have to handle negative timezones
int timeZoneOffSet = Integer.valueOf(timeSegments[1]) * 36000; // (("0100" / 100) * 3600 * 1000)
int millis = Integer.valueOf(timeSegments[0]);
Date time = new Date(millis + timeZoneOffSet);
```

Comment: Nice example, though i got an exception. It crashed when making "Integer.ValueOf" - it made an exception with invalid int. I think its because the value exceed the max value of an int.

Making it to a long instead, make it work! :)

Comment: For dealing with negative timezone please take a look at my solution based on @pablisco answer

Answer (score 3):

Copied from the accepted answer, fixed some bugs :)

```
    String json = "Date(1358157378910+0100)";
    String timeString = json.substring(json.indexOf("(") + 1, json.indexOf(")"));
    String[] timeSegments = timeString.split("\\+");
    // May have to handle negative timezones
    int timeZoneOffSet = Integer.valueOf(timeSegments[1]) * 36000; // (("0100" / 100) * 3600 * 1000)
    long millis = Long.valueOf(timeSegments[0]);
    Date time = new Date(millis + timeZoneOffSet);
    System.out.println(time);
```

Comment: Why didn't you simply fix the answer?

Comment: Ya, I've just done it. I didn't aware such kind of feature before. Thanks for letting me know. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, u can `substring` your `json` from "(" to ")", convert `string` to millis and pass in `calendar` object.

```
String millisString = json.substring(json.indexOf('('), json.indexOf(')'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get like this:

```
json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString();
```

`json` it's a `JsonElement`

EDIT: You can send without the Date(), just the numbers, can't you? And if you are using JSON, why don't work with the Date Object?

Comment: I haven't written the server side code. I just the app programmer.

Comment: Okay, you can get the whole string like a said, and them use the substring that @Veaceslav Gaidarji suggested, so you can test if the String wasn't null and if have the "(" and ")" characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
String jsonDate = "\/Date(1358157378910+0100)\/";
String date = "";
 try {
String results = jsonDate.replaceAll("^/Date\\(","");
results = results.substring(0, results.indexOf('+'));                       
long time = Long.parseLong(results);
Date myDate = new Date(time);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
date = sdf.format(myDate);
    System.out.println("Result Date: "+date);
} 
catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complete solution, based on @pablisco answer:

```
public class DateUtils {

    public static Date parseString(String date) {

        String value = date.replaceFirst("\\D+([^\\)]+).+", "$1");

        //Timezone could be either positive or negative
        String[] timeComponents = value.split("[\\-\\+]");
        long time = Long.parseLong(timeComponents[0]);
        int timeZoneOffset = Integer.valueOf(timeComponents[1]) * 36000; // (("0100" / 100) * 3600 * 1000)

        //If Timezone is negative
        if(value.indexOf("-") > 0){
            timeZoneOffset *= -1;
        } 

        //Remember that time could be either positive or negative (ie: date before 1/1/1970) 
        time += timeZoneOffset;

        return new Date(time);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other Answers such [as by pablisco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14316932/642706) are correct about parsing the string to extract the number, a count of milliseconds since epoch. But they use outmoded date-time classes.

## java.time

Java 8 and later has the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built-in. A vast improvement. Inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. Back-ported to Java 6 & 7 by the [ThreeTen-BackPort](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, which is wrapped for Android by the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

Consider the two parts of your input separately. One is a count from [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) in milliseconds, the other an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

Assuming the source used the same epoch as java.time (the first moment of 1970 in UTC), we can use that to instantiate an [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) object. An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
    String inputMillisText = "1358157378910";
    long inputMillis = Long.parseLong ( inputMillisText );
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli ( inputMillis );
```

Next we parse the offset-from-UTC. The trick here is that we do not know the intention of the source. Perhaps they meant the intended date-time is an hour *behind* UTC and so we should follow that offset text as a formula, adding an hour to get to UTC. Or they meant the displayed time is one hour *ahead* of UTC. The commonly used [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines the latter, so we will use that. But you really should investigate the intention of your data source.

```
    String inputOffsetText = "+0100";
    ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.of ( inputOffsetText );
```

We combine the `Instant` and the [`ZoneOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) to get an [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant ( instant , zoneOffset );
```

Dump to console.

```
    System.out.println ( "inputMillis: " + inputMillis + " | instant: " + instant + " | zoneOffset: " + zoneOffset + " | odt: " + odt );
```

> inputMillis: 1358157378910 | instant: 2013-01-14T09:56:18.910Z | zoneOffset: +01:00 | odt: 2013-01-14T10:56:18.910+01:00